# RabbitFoot rejects a message when not acked in 3 minutes

Tags: perl, rabbitmq

I am using `Net::RabbitFoot` library to read a message from a RabbitMQ queue. Processing the message takes some time and I want to `ack` the message **after** the processing is successful. My code is the following:

```
my $rf = Net::RabbitFoot->new()->load_xml_spec()->connect(%opts);
my $ch = $rf->open_channel();

my $msg = $ch->get(queue => 'my_queue', no_ack => 0);
frobnicate($msg); # this takes more than 3 minutes
$ch->ack(); # this has no effect, $msg is already back in queue.
```

After around 3 minutes, the (yet) un-acked message is returned back to the queue and the `ack` call has then no effect.

I don't set `timeout` or `tune` options while connecting.

Is there any way how to change the behavior so that my message is never returned back to queue unless I explicitly `reject` it?

Comment: Check the RabbitMQ server's logs. I bet your connection is dropping due to a missed heartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

Three minutes are a long time, a part that you don't seem to have any condition implying the ack (so you might switch the last two statements according also to the documentation of the protocol you are using:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf (same for 0.8.0):

```
The client layers can themselves implement explicit acknowledgements in
different ways, e.g. as soon as a message is received,
or when the application indicates that it has processed it.
These differences do not affect AMQP or interoperability.
...
Flow control
... message acknowledgements ... usually means using transactions.
```

) or you might preprocess the operability of the message in a stage before acting on it for three minutes and ack it if you operability test suceeds

on the other end this 3 minute timeout shouldn't happen, tcp established is recommended 2 hours